# Laravel relation to many tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have two tables that extend models with additional fields.

Schema:

```
additional_fields

id          int   
table_name  string(255)   (table associated with every model in my app)
key         string(255)   
desc        string(255)

additional_fields_values

id          int
field_id    int (ref on additional_fields.id)
model_id    int
value       text
```

Now I want to extend many tables with some additional fields and display them with their values. I've tried using hasManyThrough relation on model I wanted to extend:

```
public function additional_fields(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        AdditionalField::class, 
        AdditionalFieldValue::class, 
        'field_id', 
        'id', 
        'id', 
        'model_id'
    );
}
```

but it only gives me all values for one specific additional field, without its "parent". I would like to display all additional fields associated with table and values that are inserted for current instance. What is a good way to this without using many db queries?

Comment: _I've tried using hasManyThrough relation on model_ show use your try please.

Comment: Add it in the question instead please

Comment: You should be using polymorphic relationships for this.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter correct me if I'm wrong but will polymorphic relationship (morphMany) return only additional field related to the model without it's value, won't it? In that case it wouldn't work properly, because I would be supposed to define same field for the same single model everytime.

Comment: You can tack on any additional fields needed to a polymorphic tables, you're not limited in that regard. Json fields work well as catch all buckets with polymorphic models. You can create a trait or base abstract models to make the relationship easily reusable.

Comment: Can you provide any example? One that is mentioned in laravel docs is not suitable for my case.